# Close WinForm Application from different Form

Tags: c#, winforms

This may seem like a silly question, but I just want to make sure I have it right. My main form is not visible most of the time. To open it I have a NotifyIcon. One of the menu options is Exit Application. I also have a few static global variables that need to be disposed of before the application closes. so in program.cs i have this.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        InitializeApplication();
        InitializeMainForm();
        Application.Run(main);
    }
    private static void InitializeApplication()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.ApplicationExit += Application_ApplicationExit;
    }
    private static void InitializeMainForm()
    {
        main = new AssignButtonForm();
        main.FormClosing += main_FormClosing;
        Globals.StartNotify();
    }

    static void main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        var dlg = MessageBox.Show("Turn off Application?", "Exit?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        if (dlg == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Globals.notifyIcon1.Dispose();
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

So what i'm hoping is that this is the correct way to call that.

```
    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Application.OpenForms[0].Close();
    }
```

is that correct? or is there a better way?

**EDIT**

ok so one of my classes that has its own Dispose method

```
public class KeymonNotifyIcon : IDisposable
{
    public KeymonNotifyIcon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        keymonMenuStrip.SetupKeysSelected += OnSetupKeysSelected;
    }
    ~KeymonNotifyIcon()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (notifyIcon1 != null)
            notifyIcon1.Dispose();

        if (keymonMenuStrip != null)
            keymonMenuStrip.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The global class

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static TraceSource trace = new TraceSource("Keymon");
    public static KeymonNotifyIcon notifyIcon1;
    public static void StartNotify()
    {
        notifyIcon1 = new KeymonNotifyIcon();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program just shuts down, objects that have not been garbage collected will have their *finalizers* run.  It is the [recommended pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that objects implementing `IDisposable` have a finalizer to ensure that `IDisposable` is run.  To the best of my knowledge, .NET BCL classes always follow that pattern.  However, your own or third-party/open source components might not follow that pattern.

Note: The linked pattern on MSDN does not call GC.SuppressFinalize.  Check out [how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx) to reduce the GC overhead.

Implementing `IDisposable` alone isn't sufficient to ensure that the object is properly disposed.

If you have statically referenced objects that implement `IDisposable`, it is a more solid solution to explicitly call `IDisposable.Dispose()` on them from an application shut down event.

**EDIT**

Your Dispose implementation will cause Dispose() to be called twice on the owned objects because:

```
if (notifyIcon1 != null)
        notifyIcon1.Dispose();
```

does not set `notifyIcon1` to `null`, and the finalizer unconditionally calls `Dispose()` again.

Additionally, you will *always* cause the finalizer to run (which makes GC more expensive for that class) because you do not call [GC.SuppressFinalize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx) in `Dispose()`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I am fairly certain that `Application.Exit` will call all of your `Dispose` methods for you (as long as you have implemented `IDisposable`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091700/winforms-application-exit-does-not-exit-the-app-neccesarily), which references [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057151/application-exit)

Comment: all of them??? even ones that are not part of the main form that are in a global static class? (see edited post in a minute)

Comment: If you have implemented `IDisposable`

Comment: If you want to be sure to dispose everything, you could just put a Dispose-Method in your `OnFormClosing`-Event.
But that should not be necessary!

Comment: That's only true if the IDisposable objects also have a finalizer that calls IDisposable.Dispose() if the object has not yet been collected.