# Application won't end VideoStreams and Exit

Tags: c#, .net

I've got an application what's working with two video streams.
When the form is being closed, it runs this function:

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalVideoDevice.IsRunning) { FinalVideoDevice.Stop(); }
            if (streamMJPEG.IsRunning) { streamMJPEG.Stop(); }
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

But in reality it doesn't kill the application, only hides the form, but still is seen from TaskManager/Processes.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in Windows Forms you can call `Application.ExitThread();`

in general one of the reasons why you still see the process in TaskManager could be that you still have some background / worker threads active.

Roger check this question/answers as well: [Application.Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057151/application-exit)