# How to force exit application in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multi threaded C# application and it has reader writer lock,but it gives a timeout exception on some computers(not being able to acquire a lock in time) and I need to forcefully close all threads.
how do I do it without getting any extra exceptions?

Comment: `Environment.FailFast(int)` will kill your application as fast as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057151/application-exit

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Environment.FailFast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx) might be what you're looking for, but take care about the side-effects: no finalizers, finally blocks or anything else is run. It really does terminate the process **NOW**.

Comment: ok,I used it and it gave me this exception :

The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x044f07bd, on thread 0xfb0. The error code is 0x80131623. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Comment: It's worth mentioning the option of Environment.Exit. They are both guaranteed to exit pretty much immediately, but Exit does not generate a system event error event and runs the try/finally finalizer.

Comment: It isn't as "NOW" as you claim. I tried it and it takes a couple of seconds to finish its job. The other two top answers really DO work instantly.

Comment: @DanW - Hmm... Perhaps because of all the error-reporting tasks it does? I'm reading the documentation now and I'm afraid that I can't find the subtle details of how the three approaches differ. Intuitively it seems to me that `Process.Kill()` should be the most brutal way of stopping the process. I suspect it calls the [`TerminateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) Win32 API function.

Comment: @DanW -  `Environment.Exit()` sounds like a more graceful way, probably implemented in .NET itself; or maybe it's a wrapper around [`ExitProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess). And finally, `Environment.FailFast()` seems more like a debugging aid - it does stop all the user code immediately, but .NET framework code still does some hosekeeping (writing event log entry, sending data to error reporting) before fully terminating the process.

Answer (score 28):

I think the best solution to force application exit is to use the following line of code:

```
Environment.Exit(0)
```

`Environment.FailFast()` [ends up with a runtime exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast).

Comment: Thanks - this worked best for me as I wanted to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to kill program without any exception messages from system, after for example fatal error, you can use:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()
```

Answer (score 4):

To forcefully exit your application asap you can use `Environment.FailFast()`

Answer (score 2):

This might be an irrelevant answer if you are looking for an pure C# code to terminate your application, but you can use a system native form of terminating processes such as `taskkill` command, which will terminate your application for sure.

Give it a try. Add the system reference first.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Wherever you need to terminate the process,

```
String process = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c taskkill /F /IM " + process + ".exe /T");
```

- `/F` - Forces to terminate.
- `/T` - Terminates the process tree (process and any other processes started by it).
- `/IM` -
  Image Name or Process Name.