# What is the best way to stop all loops and threads when closing the main form?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, loops

My WinForm application contain many loops that takes time to complete, and many times when I click the X to close the form (and the application) I can see that the application is still running in the background, and I also see it in the Task-Manager.

What is the best way to exit all loops and threads in a clean way when the user is closing the main form?

Should I plant:

```
if (userPressedClose == true)
    break;
```

in every loop and thread that I have in my application? It looks to me like an ugly solution…

Is there a simple way to ask the application to stop all loops and threads automatically, and end the application in a clean way?

Comment: Related: [How to force exit application in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971315/how-to-force-exit-application-in-c)

Comment: Sounds like you need to use Tasks with `async` `await` and a `CancellationToken`. Then when you exit you simply cancel the token and all the code stops.

Comment: Are these loops run asynchronously at the same time?

Comment: @T.S Yes, there are several threads that runs in the background at the same time.

Comment: @ Theodor Zoulias Thanks, I used Enviroment.Exit(0);

Comment: If you have threads, run as tasks than Use cancellation token. use `onformclosing` even to set `cancel=true` on the token and all the loops will go away

Comment: @T.S I don’t know this commands, I will have to read about it and see how to use it. But my new problem is that the FormClosing() event is not firing… I have to click several times on the Form’s X icon until it reaches there…