# Application doesn't quit

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a large application with an explicit `Application.Exit()` call after a confirmation dialog. However, if I debug that application and I quit, the application doesn't close. Visual Studio still says "Running". All windows are closed.

Is there a way to find out what part of the application is still running or blocking something? I tried "Break All", but it didn't give me any useful info. Also, I have only one process and no threads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057151/application-exit

Comment: Have you tried using IntelliTrace and looking at the call stack?

Comment: You may have threads that are still running. Try using `Environment.FailFast` or `Environment.Exit`. I'd suggest fixing the problem though, look at the Threads window when you exit, see which ones are still running. You should be able to pause them and see more details about what they are doing.

Comment: @RonBeyer obviously I want to fix the problem, but I have no idea where to look.

Comment: Like I said, try looking at the threads window. You may not be explicitly creating them, but something you are using may have spun one off.

Comment: @RonBeyer I found the issue. I didn't close the database connection. Apparently a small change in it caused it to not close automatically as it did before.

Comment: You should wrap database connections in `using` statements to avoid that kind of problem in the future, glad you found it though.

Comment: @RonBeyer how would I do that if I want to keep a connection open during the entire time the application is running?

Comment: Thats a different use case I guess and wouldn't fit that pattern. Typically you want to give up connections as soon as you are finished with them, I didn't see that you were using notifications until you posted your answer.

Comment: @BartFriederichs keeping the connection open during the entire time the application is running sounds like a bad idea to me

Comment: @Sybren large part of the application is `DataGridViews` showing data from the database. Having to reconnect every time (which includes a trip to a license server in my case) a person presses F5 seems worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, it was an unclosed database connection. I added `SyncNotification=true` to the connection string, and apparently this also means the connection needs to be closed explicitly.

So, for future visitors: as other people have mentioned: check the threads, but also any connections or other possibly blocking objects.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx) Application.Exit informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed. Is any code still running in the UI thread ?

Comment: I know. The question is: how do I find out what is possibly causing that?

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Click "Pause" in VS and the debugger breaks into what's currently running.

Comment: @Joey, yes and it was only my main thread. I found the issue. It was a unclosed database connection.