# Exit my application with Yes No message box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using below code to exit my entire application application with YesNo question `messagebox` my problem is that some times I got the message twice and other times I get it correctly as one message display ..

any one can help me why that happening ??

```
    private void AppClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void F0100_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //Environment.Exit(1);
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        { e.Cancel = true; }
    }
```

Comment: Your `Show` call doesn't appear to have enough parameters.

Comment: So you are trying to brute force the entire application closed, and not just this form, correct?  And this form is _not_ the main form...right?

Comment: @DonBoitnott sorry miss-typos

Comment: @DonBoitnott yes you are right i want to close the  entire application

Comment: why not instead of this.Close() just call the code defined in F0100_FormClosing

Comment: You always need to check e.CloseReason to verify if you actually want to display this message box.  Lots of reasons not to, like WindowsShutdown.  And ApplicationExitCall :)

Comment: Rarely does a user *accidentally* exit a program.  Don't bug the user with unnecessary dialog boxes that demand their attention.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the form in question is your main form i.e. You launch this `Form` as `Application.Run(new Form1());`

If that is the case, typically you don't need to do `Application.Exit()` under the `Yes` branch from `FormClosing`. So your code should be something like below

```
private void F0100_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason  != CloseReason.UserClosing)
        return;

    DialogResult result;
    result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result != DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

The superfluous `Application.Exit()` call, creates an extra `FormClosing` event

**NOTE:** You should also check the `FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason` so you don't create an extra popup when say user is logging off or killing the process.

Answer (score 0):

Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057151/application-exit#1057159) might help you some.  Basically, you need to use the one you commented out:  `Environment.Exit(0)`.  The `Application` one is a graceful attempt at exiting *that attempts to close forms*.  Your form is still open, so it receives a 2nd `FormClosing` call.  It's all up to timing, really, but I'd think that most of the time you'd see the prompt twice.